# Simplest non-trivial monad transformer example for "dummies", IO+Maybe

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Could someone give a super simple (few lines) monad transformer example, which is non-trivial (i.e. not using the Identity monad - that I understand).

For example, how would someone create a monad that does IO and can handle failure (Maybe)?

What would be the simplest example that would demonstrate this?

I have skimmed through a few monad transformer tutorials and they all seem to use State Monad or Parsers or something complicated (for a newbee). I would like to see something simpler than that. I think IO+Maybe would be simple, but I don't really know how to do that myself.

How could I use an IO+Maybe monad stack?
What would be on top? What would be on bottom? Why?

In what kind of use case would one want to use the IO+Maybe monad or the Maybe+IO monad? Would that make sense to create such a composite monad at all? If yes, when, and why?

Comment: Have you looked at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MaybeT-0.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Maybe.html ? It gives an example of the Maybe transformer on IO.

Comment: You can have `MaybeT IO`, but not `IOT Maybe`, because `IO`, when present, must always be at the bottom of the monad stack.

Comment: The identity monad is commonly used as a base for a monad transformer stack to use code written more generally in a simple context. If you have code that works for `ContT r (ExceptT e m) a` for any `m`, you can use it in a pure context by letting `m` be `Identity`. This sort of thing is done, for instance, in streaming libraries, to use effectful streaming code in a situation where no effects ate needed.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is available [here](http://lpaste.net/8735951286651846656) as a .lhs file.

The `MaybeT` transformer will allow us to break out of a monad computation much like throwing an exception.

I'll first quickly go over some preliminaries. Skip down to **Adding Maybe powers to IO** for a worked example.

First some imports:

```
 import Control.Monad
 import Control.Monad.Trans
 import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
```

Rules of thumb:

> In a monad stack IO is always on the bottom.

Other IO-like monads will also, as a rule, always appear on the bottom, e.g. the state transformer monad `ST`.

> `MaybeT m` is a new monad type which adds the power of the Maybe monad to the monad `m` - e.g. `MaybeT IO`.

We'll get into what that power is later. For now, get used to thinking of `MaybeT IO` as the maybe+IO monad stack.

> Just like `IO Int` is a monad expression returning an `Int`, `MaybeT IO Int` is a `MaybeT IO` expression returning an `Int`.

Getting used to reading compound type signatures is half the battle to understanding monad transformers.

> Every expression in a `do` block must be from the same monad.

I.e. this works because each statement is in the IO-monad:

```
 greet :: IO ()                               -- type:
 greet = do putStr "What is your name? "      -- IO ()
            n <- getLine                      -- IO String
            putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ n         -- IO ()
```

This will not work because `putStr` is not in the `MaybeT IO` monad:

```
mgreet :: MaybeT IO ()
mgreet = do putStr "What is your name? "    -- IO monad - need MaybeT IO here
            ...
```

Fortunately there is a way to fix this.

> To transform an `IO` expression into a `MaybeT IO` expression use `liftIO`.

`liftIO` is polymorphic, but in our case it has the type:

```
liftIO :: IO a -> MaybeT IO a

 mgreet :: MaybeT IO ()                             -- types:
 mgreet = do liftIO $ putStr "What is your name? "  -- MaybeT IO ()
             n <- liftIO getLine                    -- MaybeT IO String
             liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ n     -- MaybeT IO ()
```

Now all of the statement in `mgreet` are from the `MaybeT IO` monad.

> Every monad transformer has a "run" function.

The run function "runs" the top-most layer of a monad stack returning
a value from the inside layer.

For `MaybeT IO`, the run function is:

```
runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

Example:

```
ghci> :t runMaybeT mgreet 
mgreet :: IO (Maybe ())

ghci> runMaybeT mgreet
What is your name? user5402
Hello, user5402
Just ()
```

Also try running:

```
runMaybeT (forever mgreet)
```

You'll need to use Ctrl-C to break out of the loop.

So far `mgreet` doesn't do anything more than what we could do in IO.
Now we'll work on an example which demonstrates the power of mixing 
the Maybe monad with IO.

## Adding Maybe powers to IO

We'll start with a program which asks some questions:

```
 askfor :: String -> IO String
 askfor prompt = do
   putStr $ "What is your " ++ prompt ++ "? "
   getLine

 survey :: IO (String,String)
 survey = do n <- askfor "name"
             c <- askfor "favorite color"
             return (n,c)
```

Now suppose we want to give the user the ability to end the survey
early by typing END in response to a question. We might handle it
this way:

```
 askfor1 :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
 askfor1 prompt = do
   putStr $ "What is your " ++ prompt ++ " (type END to quit)? "
   r <- getLine
   if r == "END"
     then return Nothing
     else return (Just r)

 survey1 :: IO (Maybe (String, String))
 survey1 = do
   ma <- askfor1 "name"
   case ma of
     Nothing -> return Nothing
     Just n  -> do mc <- askfor1 "favorite color"
                   case mc of
                     Nothing -> return Nothing
                     Just c  -> return (Just (n,c))
```

The problem is that `survey1` has the familiar staircasing issue which
doesn't scale if we add more questions.

We can use the MaybeT monad transformer to help us here.

```
 askfor2 :: String -> MaybeT IO String
 askfor2 prompt = do
   liftIO $ putStr $ "What is your " ++ prompt ++ " (type END to quit)? "
   r <- liftIO getLine
   if r == "END"
     then MaybeT (return Nothing)    -- has type: MaybeT IO String
     else MaybeT (return (Just r))   -- has type: MaybeT IO String
```

Note how all of the statemens in `askfor2` have the same monad type.

We've used a new function:

```
MaybeT :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
```

Here is how the types work out:

```
                  Nothing     :: Maybe String
           return Nothing     :: IO (Maybe String)
   MaybeT (return Nothing)    :: MaybeT IO String

                 Just "foo"   :: Maybe String
         return (Just "foo")  :: IO (Maybe String)
 MaybeT (return (Just "foo")) :: MaybeT IO String
```

Here `return` is from the IO-monad.

Now we can write our survey function like this:

```
 survey2 :: IO (Maybe (String,String))
 survey2 =
   runMaybeT $ do a <- askfor2 "name"
                  b <- askfor2 "favorite color"
                  return (a,b)
```

Try running `survey2` and ending the questions early by typing END as a response to either question.

## Short-cuts

I know I'll get comments from people if I don't mention the following short-cuts.

The expression:

```
MaybeT (return (Just r))    -- return is from the IO monad
```

may also be written simply as:

```
return r                    -- return is from the MaybeT IO monad
```

Also, another way of writing `MaybeT (return Nothing)` is:

```
mzero
```

Furthermore, two consecutive `liftIO` statements may always combined into a single `liftIO`, e.g.:

```
do liftIO $ statement1
   liftIO $ statement2
```

is the same as:

```
liftIO $ do statement1
            statement2
```

With these changes our `askfor2` function may be written:

```
askfor2 prompt = do
  r <- liftIO $ do
         putStr $ "What is your " ++ prompt ++ " (type END to quit)?"
         getLine
  if r == "END"
    then mzero      -- break out of the monad
    else return r   -- continue, returning r
```

In a sense, `mzero` becomes a way of breaking out of the monad - like throwing an exception.

## Another example

Consider this simple password asking loop:

```
loop1 = do putStr "Password:"
           p <- getLine
           if p == "SECRET"
             then return ()
             else loop1
```

This is a (tail) recursive function and works just fine.

In a conventional language we might write this as a infinite while loop with a break statement:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        p = raw_prompt("Password: ")
        if p == "SECRET":
            break
```

With MaybeT we can write the loop in the same manner as the Python code:

```
loop2 :: IO (Maybe ())
loop2 = runMaybeT $
          forever $
            do liftIO $ putStr "Password: "
               p <- liftIO $ getLine
               if p == "SECRET"
                 then mzero           -- break out of the loop
                 else return ()
```

The last `return ()` continues execution, and since we are in a `forever` loop, control passes back to the top of the do block. Note that the only value that `loop2` can return is `Nothing` which corresponds to breaking out of the loop.

Depending on the situation you might find it easier to write `loop2` rather than the recursive `loop1`.

Comment: What if `a` in `runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO a -> IO a`  is not a  `Maybe b` type? Is that not a problem? For example in  `survey2 :: IO (Maybe (String,String))` ?

Comment: I think you spotted a errror - I'll fix it.  `runMaybeT` should result in the `IO (Maybe a)`.

Comment: So basically, the composite monad(`MaybeT IO a`)'s  result is an "Exception" aka as `Nothing` (more precisely : `MaybeT (return Nothing)`) if anywhere in the sequence of `MaybeT IO a` monadic actions an "Exception" aka `mzero` is "thrown" aka appears. Do I understand correctly ? Then this "Exception" is manifested by executing the two monad runners and we finally get "Nothing". Much Ado About Nothing.

Comment: I've created this gist: https://gist.github.com/jhegedus42/26917d2abded3e82f427 so that this little perl of code is not lost :)

Comment: Yes, the `mzero` can even appear in a "subroutine" and exit the runMaybeT block with Nothing - to cast it in more conventional programming terms. So another way of understanding `MaybeT IO a` is that it is a computation which can use IO and which either results in an exception (Nothing) or in a value of type a (Just ...).

Comment: Yeah, and `mzero`  corresponds to throwing the exception. Sort of like a special monadic action. This is the essence of this composite monad then. Very happy to learn this finally.

Comment: Added another example of using MaybeT and mzero to write a conventional while loop.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to write a thorough and well-explained example. +1

Comment: think a missing part of the puzzle for me was that Maybe != MaybeT and turning `Maybe a -> MaybeT m a` wasn't that obvious to me either.  Your post helped me work that out: `MaybeT $ pure someMaybeValue`

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you have to work with `IO` values that "may fail" in some sense, like  `foo :: IO (Maybe a)`, `func1 :: a -> IO (Maybe b)` and `func2 :: b -> IO (Maybe c)`.

Manually checking for the presence of errors in a chain of binds quickly produces the dreaded "staircase of doom":

```
do
    ma <- foo
    case ma of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just a -> do
            mb <- func1 a
            case mb of
                Nothing -> return Nothing
                Just b -> func2 b
```

How to "automate" this in some way? Perhaps we could devise a newtype around `IO (Maybe a)` with a bind function that automatically checks if the first argument is a `Nothing` inside `IO`, saving us the trouble of checking it ourselves. Something like

```
newtype MaybeOverIO a = MaybeOverIO { runMaybeOverIO :: IO (Maybe a) }
```

With the bind function:

```
betterBind :: MaybeOverIO a -> (a -> MaybeOverIO b) -> MaybeOverIO b
betterBind mia mf = MaybeOverIO $ do
       ma <- runMaybeOverIO mia
       case ma of
           Nothing -> return Nothing
           Just a  -> runMaybeOverIO (mf a)
```

This works! And, looking at it more closely, we realize that we aren't using any particular functions exclusive to the `IO` monad. Generalizing the newtype a little, we could make this work for any underlying monad!

```
newtype MaybeOverM m a = MaybeOverM { runMaybeOverM :: m (Maybe a) }
```

And this is, in essence, how the `MaybeT` transformer [works](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#MaybeT). I have left out a few details, like how to implement `return` for the transformer, and how to "lift" `IO` values into `MaybeOverM IO` values.

Notice that `MaybeOverIO` has kind `* -> *` while `MaybeOverM` has kind `(* -> *) -> * -> *` (because its first "type argument" is a monad type constructor, that itself requires a "type argument").

Comment: Ahha, now I start to get it. I have to play around this in the evening and try to write some code using this. Many thanks. Almost perfect, in order to get an easy understand It would be good to see a simple example of actually using the `MaybeOverM` on something, anything, in action, in ghci. I will try to figure out in the evening how to do that, but if you could give me some guidance on that, that would be great.

Comment: in your `betterBind`, shouldn't it be `betterBind mia mf = MaybeOverIO $ do ...`? -- it would also be nice if you could add those missing definitions for `return` and `lift`, too, for that specific `MaybeOverIO` type, to have it all in one place, to have one complete example.

Comment: (okay, so I went ahead and fixed it...)

Answer (score 11):

Sure, the `MaybeT` monad transformer is:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT {unMaybeT :: m (Maybe a)}
```

We can implement its monad instance as so:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    return a = MaybeT (return (Just a))

    (MaybeT mmv) >>= f = MaybeT $ do
        mv <- mmv
        case mv of
            Nothing -> return Nothing
            Just a  -> unMaybeT (f a)
```

This will allow us to perform IO with the option of failing gracefully in certain circumstances.

For instance, imagine we had a function like this:

```
getDatabaseResult :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
```

We can manipulate the monads independently with the result of that function, but if we compose it as so:

```
MaybeT . getDatabaseResult :: String -> MaybeT IO String
```

We can forget about that extra monadic layer, and just treat it as a normal monad.

Comment: Many thanks AJ, "we can forget about that extra monadic layer, and just treat it as a normal monad" exactly this is what I would like to see, a simple example why using `MaybeT` would make life easier ? I don't really see where and how I should use `MaybeT . getDatabaseResult `, could you please give an example ? Something that I could run ?

Comment: There are plenty of very useful functions that mix IO and Maybe. [Hoogle helps.](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3EIO+(Maybe+b))