# understanding MonadTransformer examples

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am going through the tutorial at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers

I wrote following piece of codes. One without and other with `MonadTransformer` instance :

```
-- Simple Get Password functions. 
getPassphrase1 :: IO (Maybe String)
getPassphrase1 = do
  password <- getLine
  if isValid password
  then return $ Just password
  else return Nothing


askPassphrase1 :: IO ()
askPassphrase1 = do
  putStrLn "Enter password < 8 , alpha, number and punctuation:"
  p <- getPassphrase1
  case p of
    Nothing -> do          -- Q1. ### How to implement this with `MonadTrans` ?
      putStrLn "Invalid password. Enter again:"
      askPassphrase1
    Just password ->
      putStrLn $ "Your password is " ++ password

-- The validation test could be anything we want it to be.
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid s = length s >= 8
            && any isAlpha s
            && any isNumber s
            && any isPunctuation s
```

Another using `MonadT` which i wrote myself.

```
getPassphrase2 :: MaybeT IO String
getPassphrase2 = do
  password <- lift getLine
  guard $ isValid password
  return password

askPassphrase2 :: MaybeT IO ()
askPassphrase2 = do
  lift $ putStrLn "Enter password < 8 , alpha, number and punctuation:"
  p <- getPassphrase2
  -- Q1. How to print "Invalid password" ?
  lift $ putStrLn $ "Your password is " ++ p

-- The validation test could be anything we want it to be.
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid s = length s >= 8
            && any isAlpha s
            && any isNumber s
            && any isPunctuation s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- runMaybeT askPassphrase2
  return ()
```

Both works.

But i am unable to understand how to add `wrong password` support in `MonadTrans` example. ?

Also, is `main` method ok.. or it can be written in a better way ?

Comment: No need to bind a value to `a` if you aren't going to use it; `main = runMaybeT askPassphrase >> return ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guard` is the not what you want in the MaybeT approach. To check for an invalid password *and* be able to provide your own processing in that case you would just use your original version of `getPassphase` and *lift* it into the the `MaybeT IO` monad:

```
getPassphease2 = do result <- lift $ getPassphrase1
                    case result of
                        Nothing -> lift $ putStrLn "bad password"
                        Just pw -> lift $ putStrLn "your password is: " ++ pw
```

Explanation...

The `MaybeT IO` monad is for giving IO-actions the capability to fail *and* having that failure automatically handled by the monad. If any step fails, control goes all the way back to the `runMaybeT` and `runMaybeT` returns `Nothing`. It's like throwing an exception.

The point of using `MaybeT` is that you do no have to explicitly check to see if a step has failed - that checking is performed by the `MaybeT` monad after each step is called. That means you can write code assuming that each preceding step has succeeded - i.e. as if you were on the "happy path". This also means that you can't do something different if the previous step failed.

One possibility using the `MaybeT` version of `getPassphrase` is this:

```
main = do result <- runMaybeT askPassphrase2
          case result of
            Just _  -> return ()
            Nothing  -> putStrLn "Some failure happened... perhaps wrong password?"
```

The problem is that if `runMaybeT` returns `Nothing` it could mean that any step in `askPassphrase` failed, not just the `guard`.

Another way to use your MaybeT version of `getPassphrase` is to have `askPassphrase` run it with `runMaybeT`:

```
askPassphrase2 = do result <- lift $ runMaybeT getPassphrase2
                    case result of
                      Nothing -> lift $ putStrLn "bad password"
                      Just pw -> lift $ putStrLn $ "Your password is " ++ pw
```

Here we're using `runMaybeT` like a try-catch block.

Comment: Can you give `type` of  last example of `askPassphrase` ? Apologies for same name of functions for both versions.. i have not renamed them as `1` and `2`'s. Can you also change your answer with respect to that ?

Comment: Done - and I fixed a typo in the last code example.

Comment: Also - pehaps this SO answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32582127/866915

Comment: your `askPassphrase2` gives me compiler errors.. What is its `type` ? `lift` and `runMaybeT` is lifting `IO` further to  `t0 IO`

Comment: sorry still not compiles for me.. every line should be in same monad.. i guess line 3,4 `MaybeT IO ()` .. line 1 `MaybeT IO (Maybe String)`.. if you remove all `lift`s then it will compile but no `MabeT` usage would be their.

Comment: and i think we can not get it with `MaybeT ...` type for askPassphrase2 as `MaybeT` would not let us have failure condition. so may be we should remove all `lift`s

Comment: sorry.. my bad.. i had not put `askPassphrase2 :: MaybeT IO ()` type above the function and it was giving errors.. Thanks.