# IO (Maybe Picture) -> Picture

Tags: haskell, gloss, juicy-pixels

I'm creating a game with Gloss.
I have this function :

```
block :: IO (Maybe Picture)
block = loadJuicyPNG "block.png"
```

How do I take this IO (Maybe Picture) and turn it into a Picture?

Comment: Technically, you have an `IO` action, not a function. You call `loadJuicyPNG`, and it returns an `IO` action that, when executed, *might* result in a `Picture`.

Comment: Once you're working in the `IO` monad, you're not (normally) meant to get out of it. Whatever operation you want to apply to the resulting `Picture` (if any) should be applied within the `IO` monad. Perhaps you should clarify what you want to do with that picture in your question...

Comment: Just as a side note, you might also be interested in monad transformers in this case, such as `MaybeT IO Picture`. [A good read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32582127/4543207)

Comment: an `IO (Maybe Picture) -> Picture` type value can not exist, but `IO (IO (Maybe Picture)) -> IO Picture` can.

Comment: @WillNess `dontDoThis :: IO (Maybe Picture) -> Picture` `dontDoThis = fromJust . unsafePerformIO`. Technically, it can exist; it's just almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @JosephSible yeah. Since I am not a Haskell expert, I pretend that it does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *bind* the value. This is done either with the bind function `(>>=)`, or by `do`-notation:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    pic <- block
    case pic of
        Just p -> ...   -- loading succeeded, p is a Picture
        Nothing -> ...  -- loading failed
```

It is a `Maybe Picture` because the loading might fail, and you have to handle that possible failure somehow.

Comment: I'm still having trouble using that picture that i'm loading on my other functions. How do I do that?

Comment: @BrunoPinto Can you be more specific? If you have a function `foo :: Picture -> String`, for instance, you would just write `foo p`.

Comment: It's hard to explain, so I understand if you can't help me, but basically I need to use the the picture in several functions outside of the IO and I don't know how to do that. I'm not sure what to write in front of `Just p ->` and `Nothing ->` so that's probably what I'm missing here.

Comment: After `Just p -> ...`, you just write some regular pure code that uses `p`. Keep in mind that ultimately, the entire `do` block creates a single `IO` action that *encapsulates* your other code. Put another way, if you wrote here `... Just p -> foo p`, don't think of that as immediately running `foo` on a `Picture`; instead, you are creating an `IO` action that, when the Haskell runtime executes it, extracts `pic` from the `block` action and calls `foo` on it *for* you.

Comment: @BrunoPinto It's fine to call those other functions that don't have `IO` in them in place of the three dots; it's fine to use pure functions within IO, not so much otherwise. So your loading must always reside in the main, and then the code using it must follow, which kind of of makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same answer as Bartek's, but using a different approach.

Let's say you have a function `foo :: Picture -> Picture` the transforms a picture in some way. It expects a `Picture` as an argument, but all you have is `block :: IO (Maybe Picture)`; there may or may not be a picture buried in there, but it's all you have.

To start, let's assume you have some function `foo' :: Maybe Picture -> Maybe Picture`. It's definition is simple:

```
foo' :: Maybe Picture -> Maybe Picture
foo' = fmap foo
```

So simple, in fact, that you never actually write it; wherever you would use `foo'`, you just use `fmap foo` directly. What this function does, you will recall, is return `Nothing` if it gets `Nothing`, and return `Just (foo x)` if it gets some value `Just x`.

Now, given that you have `foo'`, how do you apply it to the value buried in the `IO` type? For that, we'll use the `Monad` instanced for `IO`, which provides us with two functions (types here specialized to `IO`):

```
return :: a -> IO a
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

In our case, we recognize that both `a` and `b` are `Maybe Picture`. If `foo' :: Maybe Picture -> Maybe Picture`, then `return . foo' :: Maybe Picture -> IO (Maybe Picture)`. That means we can finally "apply" `foo` to our picture:

```
> :t block  >>= return . (fmap foo)
block  >>= return . (fmap foo) :: IO (Maybe Picture)
```

But we aren't really applying `foo` ourselves. What we are *really* doing is lifting `foo` into a context where, once `block` is executed, `foo'` can be called on whatever `block` produces.