# Monad transformers with IO and Maybe

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, option-type, io-monad

I am trying to stack up IO and Maybe monads but either I don't understand monad transformers well enough or this is not possible using transformers. Can some one help me understand this?

```
f :: String -> Maybe String

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- getLine            -- IO String
  output <- f input           -- Maybe String (Can't extract because it is IO do block)
  writeFile "out.txt" output  -- gives error because writeFile expects output :: String
```

In the above simplified example, I have a function `f` that returns a `Maybe String` and I would like to have a neat way of extracting this in the `IO` do block. I tried

```
f :: String -> MaybeT IO String

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- getLine              -- IO String
  output <- runMaybeT (f input) -- Extracts output :: Maybe String instead of String
  writeFile "out.txt" output    -- gives error because writeFile expects output :: String
```

which lets me extract the `Maybe String` out in the second line of `do` block but I need to extract the string out of that. Is there a way to do this without using `case`?

Comment: Why did you reach for monad transformers here?

Comment: @Carl I searched for using two types of monads in a do block (which I understand is not possible) and found some threads suggesting use of `lift` and monad transformers. I didn't know much about monad transformers so took this as a learning moment. Still not sure if it's the right thing to use here.

Comment: So what do you want to happen when `f` returns `Nothing`?

Comment: I am actually not sure what would be the best way. I could throw an error and not write to the file in which case I would have to use the `case` statement so I guess that kinda answers my question?

Comment: One detail worth emphasising is that `<-` in a do-block doesn't literally extract the value from the monad. Rather, it merely allows you to work *as if* you could extract it. For instance, if you have `x <- m` in a `Maybe` do-block, you can then use the rest of the do block to specify what will be done with `x` *in case `m` is not `Nothing`*. If `m` turns out to be `Nothing`, and the possibility remains there, there will be no `x` to work with, and the failure will be propagated through `>>=` accordingly.

Comment: Right, so if `x <- m` in a `Maybe` `do` block is `Nothing`, it kinda "short circuits" the whole thing?

Comment: @Bilentor Yes.  If `m` is `Nothing` there, everything else in the block is ignored and the result of the whole thing is `Nothing`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579133/simplest-non-trivial-monad-transformer-example-for-dummies-iomaybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's stick for a moment with your first snippet. If `f input` is a `Maybe String`, and you want to pass its result to `writeFile "out.txt"`, which takes a `String`, you need to deal with the possibility of `f input` being `Nothing`. You don't have to literally use a case-statement. For instance:

- `maybe` from the Prelude is case analysis packaged as a function;
- `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` lets you easily supply a default value, if that makes sense for your use case;
- [`traverse_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_) and [`for_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_) from `Data.Foldable` could be used to silently ignore `Nothing`-ness:

  ```
  for_ (f input) (writeFile "out.txt") -- Does nothing if `f input` is `Nothing`.
  ```

Still, no matter what you choose to do, it will involve handling `Nothing` somehow.

As for `MaybeT`, you don't really want monad transformers here. `MaybeT IO` is for when you want something like a `Maybe` computation but in which you can also include `IO` computations. If `f :: String -> Maybe String` already does what you want, you don't need to add an underlying `IO` layer to it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I didn't know about `fromMaybe` which actually makes sense in my problem.

Comment: @Carl Well spotted. I have added that to the answer; thanks.

Comment: @Carl omg DUH `traverse_` for this.  I have always invented my own combinator that does the same thing.  Need to remember that `Maybe` is a "collection". Thanks.